# Animating 3 Different Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to make 3 divs fly in on click. One DIV is on top, one on the left, and one on the right (both left and right are below the top). I want to make it so that they all fly in (top from top, left from left, and right from right) when I click, using JQuery. The problem I've been having is I haven't been able to get them to fly to the right place.

Heres the JSfiddle for how its currently set up, to give you a visual picture of how I want them to fly. CSS is below. Any help is appreciated!!

https://jsfiddle.net/v59yLz3p/

heres my CSS:

```
.topcontent
    {
        top: 0;
        background-color: green;
        height: 30vh;

    }

    .leftcontent
    {
        height: 70vh;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .rightcontent
    {
        height: 70vh;
        width: 50%;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        background-color: blue;

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?. I didn't find any javascript code in your JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of like this?  Basically since you have your `vh` set you can position the elements the negative of the `top, left, and right`. Then on the button click you set the `top, left, and right` of the elements to 0 (their original location).

I added a little opacity in there as well, you can remove if you want.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v59yLz3p/2/)